Are Services automatically created for FlinkDeployments in k8s?
I have some annotations I would like to add to the (kind: Service) yaml for a FlinkDeployment but I am having trouble finding where I would add the custom annotations:
annotations:
  routing.mesh.net/enabled: "false"
  networking.istio.io/exportTo: "~"

I am using flink-kubernetes-operator 1.9-SNAPSHOT and Flink version 1.18.1.
When I do helm plan I do not see any reference to services at all. I tried adding to the FlinkDeployment under the spec.jobManager.service but got the following error:
strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.jobManager.service"

Where/how/what creates the Services for each JobManager (flink job)?
How can I add to the configuration for the Service?
Is there documentation that goes into this in detail that I missed?

Here is the FlinkDepoyment contents. Three dots (...) are just labels and annotations I removed that we specific to my company:
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: appzookeeper-control-parser
  namespace: cp-ce-cloud-infra-toc
  labels:
    ...
spec:
  mode: native
  image: "..."
  flinkVersion: v1_18
  serviceAccount: toc-flink-cluste-osd
  flinkConfiguration:
    execution.checkpointing.interval: "60s"
    heartbeat.timeout: "300000"
    taskmanager.memory.process.size: "2048m"
    high-availability.type: "NONE"
    state.checkpoints.dir: ...
    state.backend.fs.checkpointdir: ...
    state.savepoints.dir: ...
    blob.server.port: "6124"
    jobmanager.rpc.port: "6123"
    taskmanager.rpc.port: "6122"
    taskmanager.data.port: "6121"
    metrics.internal.query-service.port: "6120"
  podTemplate:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: pod-template
      labels:
        ...
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 9999
        runAsNonRoot: true
        fsGroup: 2000
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - all
            runAsUser: 9999
            runAsNonRoot: true
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          env:
            ...
            - name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
              value: -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
            - name: TOC_FLINK_JOB_DEBUG_ENABLED
              value: "true"
            - name: JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS
              value: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
            - name: JOB_NAME
              value: appzookeeper-control-parser
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/flink/log
              name: flink-logs
            - mountPath: /opt/flink/downloads
              name: downloads
            - mountPath: /data/flink/rocksdb
              name: flink-rocksdb-localdir
      volumes:
        - name: flink-logs
          emptyDir:
            sizeLimit: 5Gi
        - name: downloads
          emptyDir:
            sizeLimit: 5Gi
        - name: flink-rocksdb-localdir
          emptyDir:
            sizeLimit: 2Gi
  jobManager:
    replicas: 1
    resource:
      memory: "1g"
      cpu: 1
    service:
      annotations:
        routing.mesh.company.net/enabled: "false"
        networking.istio.io/exportTo: "~"
    podTemplate:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: job-manager-pod-template
        annotations:
          rsyslog.k8s-integration.company.com/inject: enabled
          identity.eks.company.com/use-native-identity: "true"
          opencensus.k8s-integration.company.com/inject: enabled
          logging.company.com/exclude.flink-main-container: "true"

        labels:
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: render-helm-output-manifest
          component: jobmanager
          ...
      spec:
        topologySpreadConstraints:
          - maxSkew: 1
            topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
            whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
            labelSelector:
              matchLabels:
                app.kubernetes.io/instance: render-helm-output-manifest
                component: jobmanager
                ...
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2g"
      cpu: 1
    podTemplate:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: task-manager-pod-template
        annotations:
          rsyslog.k8s-integration.company.com/inject: enabled

        labels:
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: render-helm-output-manifest
          component: taskmanager
          ...
      spec:
        affinity:
          podAffinity:
            preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
              - weight: 100
                podAffinityTerm:
                  labelSelector:
                    matchExpressions:
                      - key: component
                        operator: In
                        values:
                          - taskmanager
                      - key: p_service_instance
                        operator: In
                        values:
                          - cloud-toc-flink-cluster
                  topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
  job:
    jarURI: local:///opt/flink/lib/pipeline-1.18.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
    entryClass: com.company.toc.logparsers.job.MultilineLogParserJob
    upgradeMode: stateless
    parallelism: 1
    state: running
    allowNonRestoredState: True
    args:
      ...

